# dart double type doesn't allow fixed format

Tags: dart, double

I output the following code:

```
[v.bankClosingBalance, 0.00].firstWhere((value) => value != null)
```

and get error:

```
Exception: Uncaught Error: type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'value'.
```

which is fine as it tells me its a double. Problem is as a double I should be able to do:

```
[v.bankClosingBalance, 0.00].firstWhere((value) => value != null).toStringAsFixed(2)
```

but that gives me the error:

```
Exception: Uncaught Error: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'value'.
```

if I use double.parse around it it still says the same except with 'double'.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What does `v.bankClosingBalance` return?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer either a null or a double. class Month {double bankClosingBalance; /* ... */ }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `v.bankClosingBalance` doesn't return what you expect.
I wasn't able to reproduce this problem.

Comment: yeah my bad. I went away, came back, reloaded the script and it worked fine. School boy error! Thanks for looking into this though.